# core async - stop/resume the conveyor

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, clojurescript, core.async

I am trying to make a wrapper around websockets and I end up making a function to "connect" a `core.async` `write-channel` to the websocket `.send` function.

```
(defn ch!>ws [ws write-ch]
  (go-loop []
    (let [msg (<! write-ch)]
      (if msg
        (when
          (.send ws msg)
          (recur))))))
```

It works fine except when the websocket is closed. In this case I would like to have more control. I could decide to buffer things for a while, to throw an exception, to try to reconnect..

After searching it looks like it is not possible to stop listening/start listening to a channel when an event occurs (ex. in my case the websocket close/open events).

So is it possible to accomplish this using `core.async` (in ClojureScript), or do I have to roll my own (maybe making a queue in an atom and watch it) ?

So how do I design my program to have a behaviour similar to the conveyor start/stop ?